# Branching and merging with Git

Tags: git, git-branch

I'm unclear on a basic principle of how Git branches work.

Say I have a repo on `master` branch (which is the trunk of my project) and it's at v 1.0.  Then I decide I want to create an `experimental` branch to do some funky new stuff, so I do `git branch experimental` from the master branch and add some new functionality, and commit my changes to `experimental`.

My partner goes and updates the `master` branch to v 1.1, and I pull his changes into my `master` branch.

Will all the v 1.0 files in the `experimental` branch that were not modified by my edits to `experimental` stay current with the latest `master` files (eg. become v 1.1)?

Or do I need to merge the `master` branch into `experimental` to prevent all non-modified files in the `experimental` branch from staying at v 1.0 ?

If so, what's the process for merging these 1.1 changes into `experimental` without also contaminating the `master` branch with my funky new stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will all the v 1.0 files in the experimental branch that were not modified by my edits to experimental stay current with the latest master files (eg. become v 1.1)?

No Git will not modify any files behind your back. Maybe you want it to stay at 1.0 ;)

> Or do I need to merge the master branch into experimental to prevent all non-modified files in the experimental branch from staying at v 1.0 ?

Correct.

> If so, what's the process for merging these 1.1 changes into experimental without also contaminating the master branch with my funky new stuff?

```
$ git checkout experimental
$ git merge master
```

Answer (score 1):

On your experimental branch, run

```
git merge master
```

Comment: so `git merge master` will pull all the new stuff in the master branch into the `experimental` branch, without putting any of the `experimental` branch changes back into `master`? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Branches in Git are very light weight. This means that they are simply pointers to particular commits. Commits are linked to one another via a parent pointer. This means you don't know the children (the subsequent commits) if you have a reference to a particular one. Merges are commits with multiple parents. Branches are commits that happen to be pointed at by more than one commits' parents. Each commit also points to a snapshot of all the files in the repository.

This web of commits is referred to as the DAG (directed acyclic graph).

You can read more about it here:

http://progit.org/book/ch9-2.html

and here:

http://eagain.net/articles/git-for-computer-scientists/

Once you understand this, branching becomes clear as day! :)